# Problem with powerdot and siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx, incompatibility, powerdot

I have a problem using powerdot with siunitx.

A minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[style=simple,mode=print]{powerdot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This generates the Error `! LaTeX Error: Key 'siunitx/number-mode' accepts only a fixed set of choices.`

From the log file, it appears that importing `amsgen.sty` triggers the error, but that's not under my control.

Can I do anything, or is this a problem for the author of powerdot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because both `powerdot` and `siunitx` have a class/package option `mode`. Since the `powerdot` option must be passed as a class option (it doesn't seem to be able to be set using the `\pdsetup` command), then you need to undo that option before loading the `siunitx` package.  This can be done by emptying the internal macro that stores the class options:

```
\documentclass[mode=print,style=simple]{powerdot}
\makeatletter\let\@raw@classoptionslist\relax\makeatother
\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{A date}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thak you so much Alan